# Como puedo ejecutar esta función dentro del boton

Tags: c#, jquery, asp

Ya lo encontré la solucion: 
JS

```
function hola() {
    swal({
        title: 'Informacion',
        text: "No es posible enviar el msj sin completar su informacion.",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#03A9F4',
        cancelButtonColor: '#F44336',
        confirmButtonText: '<i class="zmdi zmdi-run"></i> Si, Completar!',
        cancelButtonText: '<i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i> No, Cancelar!'
    }).then(function () {

        window.location.href = "Usuarios_Configuracion.aspx";
    });

}
```

asp

```
<button type="button"  runat="server" onserverclick ="BTN_moda_Click">Enviar</button>
```

c#

```
  public void BTN_moda_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msj", "hola();", true);

    }
```

Ahora el problema es que me actualiza la pagina y luego corre la  "function hola()". Al parecer que a ejecutarlo desde el lado servidor siempre actualiza la pagina. Intente con:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Button type="button"  runat="server" OnClick ="BTN_moda_Click"  Text="holee" />


    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Con eso ya no actualiza la pagina pero no corre la "function hola()".

Comment: creo que necesitas usar un `<asp:button>` en vez del button normal.

Comment: @reekeecast Luego dentro del boton: Como llamo: $('.btn-edwin-system') ?

Comment: ¿Quieres que lo que hace tu código del lado del cliente con javascript hacerlo en la programación del botón en c#?

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías hacer de las siguiente forma:

```
$('#<%=Enviar.ClientID%>').click(function(){
    //código que quieres ejecutar
});
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Quiero llamarlo desde dentro del "button" lo que presenta arriba. Es decir:  

> public void BTN_Enviar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // Mis codigos y si cumple tales condiciones me llame:
          "  $('#<%=Enviar.ClientID%>') "
           o
        }